# Brute Force Generator Doesn't Tell When Password Was Guessed

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, brute-force

Alright so I'm testing a brute force algorithm I made in python. The only problem is when it gets the password I wanted it to get instead of printing out 'Password Is Correct : Password' it goes on listing the other possible options. Doesn't even pause. Here's the code:

```
import itertools
import os

lettersChar = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
numbersChar = '1234567890'
allChar = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


def CrackPassword(characters):
    realPass = input('  What Password Would You Like To Use : ')
    amount = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    for i in amount:
        gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(characters,i)
        for password in gen:
            convert = ''.join(password)
            if(convert == realPass):
                print('Password Is Correct : ' + convert)
                os.system('pause')
                return True
            else:
                print('Not Correct : ' + convert)
```

If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated :D

Comment: Show the part where you're calling `CrackPassword`

Comment: This works just fine for me using `CrackPassword(numbersChar)`

Comment: Its just CrackPassword(allChar)

Comment: The problem is it works with small passwords but when you start to combine stuff like 1aC it  won't detect it

Comment: since you use `combinations_with_replacement`, each generated password is in sorted order. so if your input is something like 321, none of your generated passwords will match your input. It seems like you want "permutations with replacement", although there's not an easy method for that like there is with `combinations_with_replacement`

Comment: Yes, not combinations. But do it yourself, don't rely on any library. That way you will have complete control over what is going on. Use combining in a way a man think. I.e. first all lower cases, then all upper, then all lower with numbers, ..., and at last mixed cases. Also, that way you may easyly add dictionary method to all. Also, I think this what you wrote is pretty slow anyway.

Comment: @Greg: "Permutations with replacement" is `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `itertools.product(chars, repeat=i)`, because you want permutations, not combinations with replacement.

You can read more about the difference between permutations, combinations, etc on [MathIsFun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html).